# Compress string to fix length with java

Tags: java, compression

How could I reduce a string lossless to a fix length of **19** characters?

My strings look like the following: *MEUCIQCE72XHhVwjnTUc2YAlV0FaCnMIAcDBDXzmyXlQh1hskgIgehf6X74JUajs77qcZrREjErYKMS08kQr9ijpSVqwqOk=*

Is any algorithm or method in java existing to solve my problem?

Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**
I have some data. For example: String1, String2, String3 and String4.
Now I have to concatenate these four strings and sign it with DSA. I would like to display the signature but it must not longer then 19 characters! Is this possible?

Comment: What is _lossless_ when you want to limit the length?

Comment: It should be able to expand the reduced string to get the original string. So the reduce operation have to be lossless?

Comment: Ohh isn't that a Base64 String. So you want to have another algorithm to shorten Base64 and get the original back. Well... this seems rather complicated.

Comment: There can not exist an algorithm that would allow to compress ANY string (even if it's Base64) to 19 characters and restore its original contents afterwards. It is impossible. The Information theory disables it.

Comment: Yes, it is a Base64 String but it is not really necessary to encode the string with Base64. Any other encoding is also possible if I get 19 characters.

Comment: Without more context information, this cannot be solved sensibly. Where does that string come from? How is it generated? You might be able to reduce the amount of data if you can provide the algorithm + parameters that produced the string.

Comment: @JimmyB I edited the post above. Do you need more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anser to your question is simply "you can't".

You haven't specified the length of the signature, but if it's 320 bits that's 40 *bytes*.

It is in the nature of encryption and signing that the output looks completely random. That's why the bytes that represent the signature data are very unlikely to be losslessly compressible *at all*.

That said, you probably already figured out that Base64 is not bad in making binary data printable (up to 75% length-efficient). Normally, signatures are displayed as hexadecimal (50% length-efficient). This however shows that you'd need even *more* than the 40 bytes binary signature length to display something legible.

So, there's no way to accomplish what you asked for.

However, you may not actually need it. If you only need a way to display *any* representative value to verify the integrity and authenticity of the message, and are not bound by any standard algorithm, you could just take the signature and feed it to a secure hash function (SHA-256 or whatever). The output of the hash function can then be used instead of the signature's value with the added benefit that you may simply truncate the hash to any desired length without breaking its security; of course, the security will degrade with shorter length however.

In 19 hex digits you can represent 76 bits, 114 bits fit into 19 Base64 digits. So if you can live with a "signature" of only 114 bits that may be a way.

Comment: Thank you. You safe my day! I can live with 114 bits :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can't convert every string losslessly to 19 characters.

It's a logical impossibility: if you could then all the information in the universe could be compressed, in successive steps, to 19 characters.

There are lossless compression algorithms available (the old-fashioned PKZIP works well with alphanumeric string data) but this will not necessarily give you the compression you need.

Comment: Maybe all the information in the universe could be compressed to 42 .